# Induction, Well-Ordering, and my Failed Proof Attempt

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, induction

I recognize there are posts already generally on the logical equivalence of induction and the well-ordering principle, however, I'd really appreciate some advice for finding the monster lurking underneath this marsh of poor reasoning. Thanks!

Complete induction $\implies$ well-ordering principle

Consider a statement $S$ where $S(n)$ states that a given subset of $\mathbb{N}$ with cardinality of $n$ has a least element.

Let, for a set $X \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, $|X| = 1$. By the reflexive axiom, $\forall a \in X, a \le a$ so $S(1)$ holds.

Now we assume $S(n)$ is true so $|X_{n}| = n$ and $\exists \ a\ \forall \ b\ : (a,b \in X) \implies a \le b$.

$S(n+1)$ would state that the well-ordering principle holds for a set $X_n \cup {z}$ where $z$ is a new element.

Since the well ordering principle held on $X$, there is a least element of $X$, call it $a$. Now $(z \le a)\vee (z > a) $. If the former is true than $z$ is now the least element. If the latter is true then $a$ is still the least element.

Why is this seemingly much more obvious "solution" wrong? I have a gut feeling this has something to do with considering arbitrary elements of the power-set of $\mathbb{N}$ - which is uncountably infinite - and forming a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to these subsets of $P(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: it looks good to me, why do you think it's wrong? (Actually I'd change the formulation, but the logic itself looks fine)

Comment: when a young man such as myself sees that that status quo differs, is he not filled with self doubt?

Comment: Again, but less in prose?

Comment: Did you not know that Weak Induction $\iff$ Strong Induction $\iff$ Axiom of Choice $\iff$ Zorn's Lemma $\iff$ Well Ordering Principle $\iff$ Tychonoff's theorem $\iff$ Krull's theorem $\iff$ every vector space has a basis $\iff$ Tukey's Lemma $\iff \dots$

Comment: Change the formulation how? I've seen other examples but what motivates choosing the less obvious proof over this one?

Comment: Note that the only thing that you proved here is that each finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ has a smallest element, not that each non empty subset of $\mathbb{N}$ has one.

Comment: Mostly style, for instance starting sentences with symbols (even $S$) is bad. Maybe apply induction a bit more clearly, a bit more verbose about it. And also like Max said, I'd make sure that each step is crystal clear. Mostly style, not so much logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Max noted in the comments, you only have proved that any *finite* nonempty subset of $\mathbb N$ has a minimal element.

Note that also every finite subset of $\mathbb R$ has a minimal element, and yet $\mathbb R$ is not well-ordered. Indeed, your prove works unchanged also for finite subsets of $\mathbb R$, since the only property of $\mathbb N$ *as the set you're taking subsets of* is the order (you are using additional properties of $\mathbb N$ *as cardinality of the set,* but that is independent from the set from which you're taking the subset).

Comment: But that's not a problem where induction or the well ordering principle play a role.

Comment: @martin.koeberl: I don't understand what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: The question was why the OP's solution was wrong. You answered that, but your answer would have been much better by saying how to fix the proof. Namely that if $A\subseteq \mathbb N$ and $A$ is infinite, then you can choose any element $n\in A$, and $A\cap (n+1)$ is finite and its least element will be the least element of $A$.